# return the first image src of a page with Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension and I want to show the first image of a webpage (for instance: a blog) in the popup.htm. So far I know how to implement the favicon so I was trying to work backwards and edit the favicon into the first image of the page. The problem is the favicon was so simple! All I had to write for a given variable was

```
function favicon(a)
{
return "chrome.../" +a;
}
```

Now, I can find the img.src of a background page. But I'm not sure how to find one of a unique page (submitted by the user). I've googled every way my vocabulary permits and so far have come up with this...

```
function getLavicon(a)
{
  /*
  find first image on page requested
  get url of first image
  return url
  */

  return $(localStorage.getItem(a)).find('img').first().attr('src'); 
}
```

It returns a blank image. Let me know if screenshots are necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Why use jQuery for this ? You can get the first image url on the page by using the following code:

```
var firstImage = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
console.log(firstImage.src) // This will print out the source of the image on the console
```

Now you can use the source of the first image whenever you want just by using `firstImage.src`
Pretty sweet and clean huh ? :)